# WP Rest Api / Ajax POST not working when not logged in

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest-api

Following the [Wordpress documentation about the Rest Api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), i can manage to make an ajax POST working, but only when logged in to Wordpress.  Here are the basic files shown in the documentation:

#### functions.php

```
wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
    'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
) );
```

#### app.js

```
$.ajax( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        'title' : 'Hello Moon'
    }
} ).done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
} );
```

I'm showing this example as it is presented as an easy one, but is **not working** when not logged in.   It is always giving me a 401 Unauthorized response / “rest_cannot_create”...

Any tip ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the safest way, but this plugin is still working today :

[Basic Authentication handler](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth)

Once installed, using Javascript, we'll just use the **Base64 variable** :

`var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}};`

... and **add in the `beforeSend` function** :

`xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 'YOUR_USER_NAME' + ':' + 'YOUR_PASSWORD' ); );`

Bingo !

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation page you linked,

> It is important to keep in mind that this authentication method relies on WordPress cookies. As a result this method is only applicable when the REST API is used inside of WordPress and the current user is logged in. In addition, the current user must have the appropriate capability to perform the action being performed.

Your JavaScript function is attempting to update a post - an interaction which affects the site's database. Thus the REST API requires authentication in order to perform the operation. While REST authentication behaviors can be modified using the [`rest_authentication_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_authentication_errors/) filter, it's **highly** inadvisable to disable authentication for the requests which require them by default, as doing so exposes your site to modification at virtually anyone's whim.

You may wish to investigate alternate means of authentication, as alluded to [in the documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins) you linked.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.  I have tried them all for months now (OAuth, JWT, ...) ... there is always something going wrong.  Feeling like I'm dumb.  While i was trying to 'shadow login' as a hack to make POST work, yesterday a WP moderator wrote :  "to post specific content does not necessarily require the user be logged in. A custom handler for requests sent to admin-ajax.php or admin-post.php can insert new posts or whatever without the user being logged in".    So i went back to try stuff, still without success...     May i ask what is your favorite way of authentication ?  Cheerz...

Comment: I actually haven't written anything using the REST API which requires authentication - just front-ends displaying content. I'm rather fond of OAuth (though I'm not a big fan of setting it up!). What are you working on that you should want to be able to add/update posts without being logged in? The WP mod makes a good point - if you write your own AJAX handlers, you can decide whether or not a user must be logged in to do something simply by whether or not you include a `is_user_logged_in()` (or similar) check.

Comment: I need any visitor to be able to post ads from the front end (as draft).  It is working perfectly when I'm logged in.   Having so many difficulties to authenticate, i did try a 'shadow login' for any visitor, but then i had other problems with getting a [wrong nonce on first load](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261044/wp-rest-api-nonce-incorrect-on-first-load)
This is getting me nuts :)

Comment: Ah alright - I see what you're getting at. I think I have a two-part solution for you which comprises the "most WordPress-y" way to accomplish this - and we get to ignore authentication woes all together to boot. You'll need to register a custom post type to represent ads, and create a REST endpoint controller class which will determine how the new custom post type is available through the REST API. This will let you specify custom CREATE permissions allowing visitors to create ads while not exposing other content to visitor whims.

Comment: I can pull together a more complete answer tomorrow, - maybe throw it in a new "Visitor Posting via the REST API" question for posterity